# Existence of solution of some functional equation involving integral

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, functional-equations, adjoint-operators

I want to prove that there exists always solutions to this equation
$$g(x) = \int\limits_a^b {f(s,x)ds} $$
where $g \in {L^2}(0,1)$ is given and $f \in {L^2}((a,b) \times (0,1))$ is the uknown, $0<a<b<1$ are just to positive constants.
If I consider the operator $$\eqalign{
  & T:{L^2}((a,b) \times (0,1)) \to {L^2}(0,1)  \cr 
  & f \to \int\limits_a^b {f(s,x)ds}  \cr} $$
the surjectivity peoblem turn to the existence of a positive constant $c$ such that 
$${\left\| {{T^*}h} \right\|_{{L^2}(0,1)}} \geqslant c{\left\| h \right\|_{{L^2}((a,b) \times (0,1))}}$$
The formal ajoint of $T$ is given by ${T^*}h =h$, therefore, we can write
$${\left\| {{T^*}h} \right\|_{{L^2}(0,1)}} = \int\limits_0^1 {{h^2}(s)ds = } \int\limits_a^b {\int\limits_0^1 {{h^2}(s)dsdx = } } \frac{1}{{b - a}}{\left\| h \right\|_{{L^2}((a,b) \times (0,1))}}$$.
Am I write? thank you.

Comment: Why not just take $f(s,x) = g(x)/(b-a)$?

Comment: Yes, this is one possibility, but I want to know if my proof is correct.